# how can we retrieve data from database in ASP.NET using VB as language?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-access-layer

i need the complete code for retreiving the data from a database.. i m coding in visual web developer and using VB as coding language. I m using SQL SERVER as database handler.

Comment: there are many examples on the web: http://www.google.co.nz/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enNZ329NZ329&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=vb.net+ado.net. Maybe you have a slightly more specific example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What kind of database? SQL Server? Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Shared Dim con As SqlConnection

Shared Sub Main()
    con = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI") 

    ' Create the command object
    Dim str As String = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Employee"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    da.Fill(ds, "Employee")

    gridview1.datasource=ds;//
     gridview1.databind();// to bind the data to gridview
```

its will be help to u..

Answer (score 0):

[Samples here might work for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.71).aspx)